# How to add a pause before a comma in the TTS character filter for google tts in moonreader app for android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, reader

I see the TTS character filter section. how do I add a delay before a character in this section? I want the comma to be preceded by a pause n (ms).

[image: moonreader tts]

Answer (score 0):

I have been using full-stops as a "pause intonation", it might be too long a pause but this is what I'm currently using, just replace commas with full-stops.

```sh
,  ==  .
```